# Problems with page loading data on JS

Tags: javascript, database, axios

I have a problem with my code, when the page is loading and the code is starting running The code works very fast, and even before it is enough to reach all the lines it already continues to run.
What happens is that the page does not get the data disability and I'm not getting the users right way.

Here is my code:

```
 var users = [{}]
    getUsers();
    function getUsers() {
        const res = http.get('users/')
        .then(res => {
            users = res.data
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

mock.onPost('/api/auth/access-token').reply(config => {
    const data = JSON.parse(config.data);
    const { access_token } = data;
    
            try {
                const { id } = jwt.verify(access_token, jwtConfig.secret);
                const usersID = window.localStorage.getItem('usersId')
                const user = _.cloneDeep(users.find(_user => _user.uuid === usersID));
                delete user.password;
                const updatedAccessToken = jwt.sign({ id: user.uuid }, jwtConfig.secret, { expiresIn: jwtConfig.expiresIn });
    
                const response = {
                    user,
                    access_token: updatedAccessToken
                };
    
                return [200, response];
            } catch (e) {
                const error = 'Invalid access token detected';
                return [401, { error }];
            
        }
            
        
});
```

if you have an idea how to fix the code I will be very happy.
Thanks

Comment: shouldnt your users be on the users array?

Comment: Yes, I'm getting all the details from the dB, it's actually a array of objects

Comment: the reason you're not getting the users right away is because getUsers is an asynchronous function, so when you call getUsers(), the main thread immediately executes the next line without waiting for users to be populated.

Comment: So what's the best way to fix the code?

Comment: use async .... await... Do you know how to use it?

Comment: Yes, I've tried to use that,  but it's not helping